# Javascript Substring not working with special characters

Tags: javascript, xml, substring

Hi there I'm trying to use the following

```
sValue.substr(0,1000);
```

on the string

`&lt;ul class='ulIndentRight'&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;b&gt;Altissimo Guesthouse&lt;/b&gt; &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Luxury Room With Queen Bed Rtid 1 &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Extra&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;person Charges May App Superior Room 1 Queen Bedlayout &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Bedroom Internet &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Free Wifi Entertainment &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Plasma Tv&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Satellite Channels&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; And Dvd Playerfood &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Drink &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Refrigerator&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Free Minibar Items&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Coffee&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;tea Maker&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; And Free Bottled Waterbathroom &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Private Bathroom&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Bathtub Or Shower&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Free Toiletries&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; And A Hair Dryerpractical &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Safe&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Desk&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; And Iron&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;ironing Board (on Request) Rollaway&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;extra Beds Available On Requestcomfort &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Climate&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;controlled Air Conditioning And Daily Housekeepingnon&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;s`

but it keeps on returning a character count of 1136

any ideas how to get only 1000 characters

Thanks

Comment: I've tried your code on the string provided and I get 1000 as the length.

Comment: Are you using the return value from `substr`?

Comment: Hi I left out that this javascript is called in xsl stylesheet that the substring is returning the full string because in xsl actually first does this hidden xml conversion, then length thus stays at 800.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's HTML special characters.

I think the easiest way:

1. you create a temporary element
2. you put your string in the HTML of the element (innerHTML)
3. you put the characters from this element with textContent in new string
4. you make the count on this string

```js
let string = 
        "&lt;ul class='ulIndentRight'&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;b&gt;Altissimo Guesthouse&lt;/b&gt; &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Luxury Room With Queen Bed Rtid 1 &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Extra&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;person Charges May App Superior Room 1 Queen Bedlayout &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Bedroom Internet &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Free Wifi Entertainment &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Plasma Tv&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Satellite Channels&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; And Dvd Playerfood &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Drink &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Refrigerator&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Free Minibar Items&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Coffee&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;tea Maker&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; And Free Bottled Waterbathroom &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Private Bathroom&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Bathtub Or Shower&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Free Toiletries&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; And A Hair Dryerpractical &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Safe&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Desk&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; And Iron&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;ironing Board (on Request) Rollaway&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;extra Beds Available On Requestcomfort &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt; Climate&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;controlled Air Conditioning And Daily Housekeepingnon&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;s";
        
            document.querySelector('.string').innerHTML = string;

  let string_div = document.querySelector('.string').textContent;
  charCount = Array.from(string_div).length;
  document.querySelector('.count').innerHTML = charCount;
  console.log(charCount);
```

```html
<div class="string" style="display:none">
</div>

<div class="count">
</div>
```

Comment: You deserve a medal for guessing the OPs intent :)

Answer (score 1):

1136 is the length of your entire string.

I suspect that you are not using the return value from `substr`.

You will need to assign the return value and use that instead as `substr` does not modify the original value.

```js
sValue.substr(0,1000);
// sValue.length => 1136

const newString = sValue.substr(0,1000);
// newString.length => 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let value = "Paste_whole_string_in_here"
console.log(value.substring(0,1000))
```

This is working for me.